# Why do I get this 'Object reference not set [...]' error on this array?

Tags: unity, c#

I get:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

on line 22 of the following code. I tried digging online but I can't seem to find any solution. Please help.

```
public class Button{
    public bool free;
    public Vector3 worldPos;
    public Vector2 screenPos;
    public int Type;

    public Button(bool _free){
        free = _free;
    }
}

public class PlayerMobility : MonoBehaviour {
    const int MaxBtn = 20;
    Button[] Buttons = new Button[MaxBtn];

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //Buttons = new Button[MaxBtn];
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxBtn; i++) {
            print ("init");
            Buttons[i].free = true; //< object reference not set to an instance of an object 
                                    //  error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh its a simple syntax error. I see why this was flagged as off-topic. Recasting my vote

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C# programmer, but I gave this a shot. Apparently new Button[MaxBtn] only constructs an array, but doesn't initialise it's contents (which makes sense - how would it when you're not providing a constructor argument?). So what you're getting is an array with MaxBtn null references.

If you replace your crashing line with

```
Buttons[i] = new Button(true);
```

everything will work and the array elements will be correctly constructed.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is you haven't instantiated actual buttons into your array.

When you call `new` with the code

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[MaxBtn];
```

you have set aside all the spots for the array, but at those memory locations there are no buttons yet.

what you need to do after creating the array is iterate through and instantiate buttons at each index.

```
  for(int i=0; i<MaxBtn; i++){
    buttons[i] = new Button(); 
   }
```